# Comparing elements of an array to each other

Tags: c, arrays

```
for (x=1; x<=4; x++){
    slope = ((x+1)-(x))/(a[x+1] - a[x]);
    printf("Slope: %d \n", slope);
}
```

So, yes. This is a homework question. I'm trying to compare every element of the array `a = {1, 2, 3, 4}` against every other element and find the slope. The `x`'s are the values and `y`'s are the indexes. Is this doing it? Shouldn't there be 16 slopes?

Comment: Please correct your question. You mentions `Ys` but have no `Y` in the code. You compute `slope` but print `v`. Don't make us guess what you really mean.

Comment: @SteveFallows - Im trying to find the slope of each element against every other element. My X values are my Array values and my Y values are my array indexes

Comment: But in your code you're using x as the array index. And `(x+1) -(x)` will always equal 1. So I still find it hard to correlate your code with what you say you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Arrays in C are zero-based.  You're looping from a[1] to a[4] and should be looping from a[0] to a[3].  Your code will result in an array out-of-bounds error.

Look into nested loops.

Comment: Note `a[x+1]` so `x < 4` would still result in out-of-bounds.

Comment: No, actually, it produces 4 slopes. I think i need 16 though, since I'm comparing every element against every other element.

Comment: Well you said your array has 4 elements, and if it does, then the fourth iteration of your loop will cause a[4] to be accessed, and there is no a[4] in a 4-element array.

Comment: @user1079940 - There is no way the compiler is correcting your "off-by-one" error, fyi.

Answer (score 2):

To compare every element of an array to every other element, you need 2 nested loops.  Assuming array `A` has length `n`, to compare every element to every other element, do:

```
int A[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
unsigned int n=sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);
int i,j;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    if(i != j)
      printf("Slope is %d\n",(i-j)/(A[i]-A[j]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
Slope is 1
```

The reason for the `if(i != j)` is because you can't calculate the slope between 2 identical points, which occurs when `i==j`.

Also, as mentioned, arrays are `0-indexed`, which means you should access elements from `A[0]` to `A[n-1]`, as demonstrated by my loops above.

Comment: Haha I was trying to give him hints instead of posting code since it's a self-admitted homework assignment. :)

Comment: @prelic So, here, is A[i] actually my indexes and A[j] my values?

Comment: @user1079940 - I'm not sure what formula you're using to calculate "slopes".  Slope is usually calculated between 2 points, not just 2 numbers, so I'd need to know what the formula of a slope between 2 numbers is.  You said you wanted to compare each element to each other element.  A[i] is the "each element", and A[j] is the "each other element".  So for every cycle of the outer-most loop, your inner loops cycles over the entire array (`n` times).

Comment: @prelic - Im trying to find the slope of each element against every other element. My X values are my Array values and my Y values are my array indexes

Comment: @user1079940 So for the formula `m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)`, `y1` is `i`, `y2` is `j`, `x1` is `A[i]` and `x2` is `A[j]`

Comment: @prelic - Still not doing it... for (i=0; i<4; i++){
   for (j=0; j<4; j++){
    slope = ((j)-(i))/(a[j] - a[i]);
   }
   printf("Slope: %d \n", slope);
  }

Comment: @user1079940 - what is not working? You should use a debugger to figure out what results you are getting, as opposed to what you want.  It's an invaluable skill.

Comment: @prelic Im getting an Arithmetic Exception

Comment: @user1079940 - is the array initialized correctly? If `a[j]-a[i] == 0`, then you'll get an exception for dividing by 0.

Comment: @user1079940 - The arithmetic exception happens when you calculate the slope between the same point.  You can't do that.  I edited my answer to reflect this caveat.